# Nextjs with Styled components not passing theme

Tags: react-native, next.js, styled-components

I'm trying to pass my theme object to `styled-components` on my Next.js project, but it keep's failing to receive it as a props.

That's my `_document.tsx`

```js
import { getInitialProps } from "@expo/next-adapter/document";
import Document,  { DocumentContext, DocumentInitialProps }  from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}
```

After that I wrapped my `_app.tsx` with the `ThemeProvider`

```js
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import 'setimmediate';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { wrapperStore } from "../store";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import client from './api/apollo-client';
import React from 'react';
import lightTheme from '../helpers/light-mode';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </ThemeProvider>
     </ApolloProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
export default wrapperStore.withRedux(MyApp);
```

From here I receive a warning when I try to wrap my component, exporting it `withTheme`

```
[withTheme] You are not using a ThemeProvider nor passing a theme prop or a theme in defaultProps in component class "Connect(Front)"
```

when I try to console log `theme` from my props, it returns undefined,  and when I create a styled component, trying to use `theme` as props it causes an error

```js
export const RecruitmentTextLocation = styled.Text`
    fontSize: ${scaleFont(15)};
    textAlign: left;
    marginTop: ${scale(5)}px;
    marginBottom: ${scale(1)}px;
    fontFamily: roboto;
    fontWeight: 500;
    color: ${({theme}) => theme.colors.cardTitleColor};
`;
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined`

I'm really stuck on how I can use theming with styled-components on Nextjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you problem is in *light-mode.tsx*. How can i see you  use *typescript* in that case need create a *declarations file* and *DefaultTheme* interface. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-matan-4j524?file=/src/theme.ts)

> Create a declarations file
> TypeScript definitions for styled-components can be extended by using declaration merging since version v4.1.4 of the definitions. [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#create-a-declarations-file)

**light-mode.tsx**

```js
import { DefaultTheme } from 'styled-components';

export const lightTheme: DefaultTheme = {
  colors: {
    cardTitleColor: red;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same and found a solution for typing the `theme` object you receive as prop on your styled components.

First, export the types of your themes, e.g.:

```js
export type LightTheme = typeof lightTheme;
```

Then add a `src/declaration.d.ts` file with the below, so to enhance the `DefaultTheme` exported by `styled-components` to be typed with your custom theme object:

```js
import { Theme } from "globalStyles";

declare module "styled-components" {
  export interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

From there you won't need any `withTheme` to use your theme object, as you will simply be able to access it through:

```js
color: ${({theme}) => theme.colors.cardTitleColor};
```